# When importing a CSV, how do I handle data in a row that corresponds to an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, import

I am following the [Import CSV Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast) and it is straight forward.

The issue is that it deals with just a csv file containing only information in 1 model in 1 file.

Say, I have a CSV file that I am trying to import to my `Listing` model. On each row/listing it has a column called `Building` where the value is actually the name of the building attribute of that listing (i.e. `@listing.building.name`).

How do I handle those cases in the import?

This is the closet that Ryan gets in that Railscast, which is on the `Product` model in his case:

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    product = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
    product.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
    product.save!
  end
end
```

All that is happening is that he is checking to see if the product exists and if it does then update the attributes. If it doesn't, then create a new one.

Not quite sure how to handle the associations in this case...especially given that what needs to happen is in the event that an associated record doesn't exist, it needs to be created during this process.

So going back to my `building.name` example earlier, if there is no `Building.find_by_name(name)`, then it should create a new building record.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    product = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
    product.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
    product.save!

    building = product.buildings.find_by_name(row['building_name'])
    building ||= product.buildings.build
    building.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*build_accessible_attributes)
    building.save!
  end
end
```

UPDATE: updated answers using new rails 3 methods

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    product = where(id: row["id"])
      .first_or_create!(row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes))

    product.buildings.where(name: row['building_name'])
      .first_or_create!(row.to_hash.slice(*building_accessible_attributes))
  end
end
```

Comment: Why do I get this error message: `undefined method 'path' for nil:NilClass` at the line `CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|`? This happens when I click the 'browse' button.

Comment: you need to create another question for that

Comment: Was about to, but figured I would try first :)

Comment: Done...can you check it out for me please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643449/undefined-method-path-for-nilnilclass-when-trying-csv-import Thanks. Once I can get passed that issue, I can get to test your answer here and accepting if it is right :)

Comment: If your using an up to date version of rails/active_record then should try to use `first_or_create` [rails api](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create).  Which would make the code cleaner

Comment: @bullfrog it will make the code cleaner but that would mean 2 writes to the db since you need to add some attributes after.

Comment: Maybe he meant `find_or_create`? The only issue with that is can you do `find_by_id_or_create`?

Comment: Its become standard to use `first_or_create` rather than use `find_or_create` [Rails Active Record Query](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#first_or_create)