# undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass when trying CSV import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, import

I am following the [Import CSV Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast) and it is straight forward.

I added `require 'csv'` to my `config/application.rb`

In my `BuildingsController` I created a new `import` action like so:

```
def import
  Building.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Buildings imported."
end
```

In my view, I have this:

```
<h2>Import Buildings</h2>
<%= form_tag import_buildings_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

This is in my `Building.rb` model:

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    building = find_by_name(row["name"]) || new
    building.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
    building.save!
  end
end
```

In my `routes.rb`, I have this:

```
  resources :buildings do
    collection { post :import }
  end
```

When I click the 'import' button on my view, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError at /buildings/import

Message undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass
File    /myapp/app/models/building.rb
Line    23
```

Thoughts?

Comment: that means that `params[:file]` is `nil` but I can't see why it is unless you submit the form without choosing a file

Comment: Oh wow...I am soo embarrassed. I was importing an empty form :( The way the form is and the styling in my app, it just had 1 button for the import. I was choosing that thinking I was pressing 'select file'. My bad.

If you add that as an answer, I will accept it. *hides face*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment: You are most probably submitting the form without choosing a file :)