# Importing associated models from single csv in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, import

I've been following rails cast episode, [Importing CSV and excel](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast), but I have a slightly different setup.

I have two models, usage(amount) & price(amount). I have it set up so usage has_one price and price belongs_to a usage. In my csv, I have two columns, like so:

```
usage,price
1000,0.1
1500,0.11
```

I'm trying to import the data so that I can get usage.amount & usage.price.amount into my database.

I had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642121/when-importing-a-csv-how-do-i-handle-data-in-a-row-that-corresponds-to-an-assoc?rq=1), and tried everything there. One thing to note is that I don't have an id column (although I tried with an id column and the code from that question still didn't work).

Here is the code from my model:

```
class Usage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :price, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :price


  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      Usage.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
end
```

Note: I know the above has no reference to importing the price.amount, but anything I tried wouldn't work.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Update**

Here's how I got it working:
(Thanks to **alalani** for helping with the following code.)

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
  u = Usage.create(amount: row[0])
  u.create_price(amount: row[1])
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply create new instances of the class and add it manually?

So you could do:

```
def self.import(file)    
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        u = Usage.new(:amount => row[0])
        u.save
        p = Price.new(:amount => row[1])
        p.save
        u.price << p
    end
end
```

It seems like a little bit more work, but its very simple to understand whats going on here

Comment: Cheers! I got an "undefined method" for the << but it worked when I used u = Usage.create(amount: row[0]) and u.create_price(amount: row[1]).