# Rails Import Nested Attributes CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to implement an import with its nested attributes following closely to:
[Rails Cast CSV Import](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel)

An example of the string to import is as such:

id  subject_list_name   subject_codes

```
1   CE2A    [CPE205, CPE206, CPE301, CPE302, CPE303]
```

With the following codes, I am trying to import

1. Data for the Subject List model (id and subject_list_name)
2. A many-to-one Relationship with data from the Subject model-Subject list has many Subjects (subject codes)

Right now, I am able to import the data for the subject list but faced problems importing data for the relationship. (i.e. I can get changes in subject list name to work but not for subject codes)

The following code segment is what I have done.

```
  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

      #each row
      subject_list = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
      subject_list.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
      subject_list.save!

      subject_codes = row["subject_codes"]
      subject_codes = subject_codes.delete('[]')
      subject_codes = subject_codes.split(', ')

      #each subject code
      subject_codes.each do |code|
        subject_list.subjects.where(subject_code:code)
         .first_or_create!(subject_code:code)
      end

    end
  end
```

Any advice on how I could implement the relationship between the two would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When importing a CSV, how do I handle data in a row that corresponds to an association?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642121/when-importing-a-csv-how-do-i-handle-data-in-a-row-that-corresponds-to-an-assoc)

Comment: I have tried that the solution out but gotten this error instead: undefined local variable or method `subject_accessible_attributes'

Comment: that means you need to define `subject_accessible_attributes`. just pass it an array of attributes that you're expecting on the csv

Comment: Thanks. I tried out that method but it resulted in creation of new subject instances for me but I wanted it such that these instances already exist and for the method to join them together. I ended up doing the following which works for now but is way slower in performance.       subject_list.subjects.delete_all
      
      subject_codes.each do |code|
        subject = Subject.find_by_subject_code(code)
        subject_list.subjects << subject
      end